# Livequery in asp.net

Tags: jquery

I'm using this CDN

```
 <script src="http://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery/raw/master/jquery.livequery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But the LiveQuery Option is not popping out..?

Thanks...I'm getting LiveQuery Option NOw. But my actaul issue was:
The Change option in the LIVE Method is not working with IE. So I used the code like this..

```
$('#<%=Combobox1.ClientID%>').livequery("change", function () {
 ShowLoadingPanel();});
```

It's not working at all....:-(...I'm working on this issue for 4 days....Any Help would be appreciated...btw I already tried Bind, ON, Delegate Methods with no help....

Comment: Have you include the Jquery script?

Comment: Yes.I've 4.  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: can you post the full <script> on your question?

Answer (score 0):

Do not include two times jQuery since it can possibly have conflict. You just need one jQuery library and one jQuery UI library.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks....I'm getting LiveQuery option now....Sorry to be pain..but plz check my question once again...

Comment: Sure, I'll close. Just I got another issue. I request you to plz check the question..

Comment: Do you wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function() { });` as well as make sure your `id` is correct.

Comment: Yes, inside $(document).ready(function() { }) and id is correct. The Live Method is working with all the other Browsers except IE. SO i thought of using LiveQuery but still it is not working....